# Bizarre Invalidate behaviour

Tags: android, view, media-player, invalidation

I have a custom viewgroup (Custom2) inside a custom viewgroup (Custom1).

Custom1 has an imageview displaying a RectShape Shapedrawable and two textviews.

I set an onClickListener in Custom2 which removes the imageview using this.removeViewAt(0) and creates a new TextureView, then calling this.addView (mTextureView, 0) and finally invalidate. I then get the textureview to play a video using mediaplayer.

Here is the code:

```
public void setToTextureView() {
        //TextureView when not debugging
        TextureView View;
        View = (TextureView) new TextureView(mContext);
        View.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(600, 500));
        this.removeViewAt(0);
        this.addView(View, 0);
        View.invalidate();
        Log.d("Debug", "Invalidate Called");

        View.setSurfaceTextureListener(new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
                Surface mSurface = new Surface(surface);

                MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(); //Debug MediaPlayer issues by setting ItemToDebug = "MediaPlayer"
                try {
                    mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(mContext, Uri.parse("android.resource://" + mContext.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.t));
                    if (ItemToDebug.equals("MediaPlayer")) {
                        Log.d("MediaPlayer", "Data source set");
                    }
                    mMediaPlayer.setSurface(mSurface);
                    if (ItemToDebug.equals("MediaPlayer")) {
                        Log.d("MediaPLayer", "Surface set");
                    }
                    mMediaPlayer.prepare();
                    if (ItemToDebug.equals("MediaPlayer")) {
                        Log.d("MediaPLayer", "Prepared");
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d("IOException", e.getMessage());
                }
                mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        if (ItemToDebug.equals("MediaPlayer")) {
                            Log.d("Debug", "Media Player Prepared");
                        }
                        mp.start();
                    }
                });
            }
```

Now, I notice bizarrely that the ImageView disappears and an empty space appears (of the correct size) when I click the view, but no video plays, although the code appears to execute fine upto invalidate();

However, I can then get the TextureView to get a surfaceTexture and play the video when I interrupt the program and go back in (i.e by pressing the button that takes you to the screen with all the open programs, and selecting my activity again.)

I don't have a good understanding of exactly what is happening but I am pretty sure that no SurfaceTexture is being created because onAttached() isn't being called.

Does anybody know what might be going on?

Cheers,

J

Comment: tried hierarchyviewer?

Comment: No I haven't. Thanks for the tip...i'll check it out. However, I'm still intrigued  why the bug is occurring...I've done nearly identical things in the past, but this is the first time this has happened.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29731150/android-view-bizarre-behaviour - See my related question. Its not just the textureviews but also just viewgroups in general.

Answer (score 0):

The view disappears, I need to call requestLayout() in order to draw something else there.